# Have to show Model data into View using JavaScript MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have page where I save user, contact and address details. The users could have multiple contact and address, So I have added the control to populate dynamically.

Form is working fine, except if any exception occurrs, the controller action return view with model.

This follows the structure of Model:

Model

```
public class UserModel
{
    public UserDetail User { get; set; }
    public IList<UserContact> Contact { get; set; }
    public IList<UserAddress> Address { get; set; }
}
```

Contact Model :

```
public partial class UserContact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Address Model

```
public partial class UserAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
    public string AddressName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}
```

When value return, the following function suppose to check the Contact and Address and then then populate each record in dynamic created input section in view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

AddDynamicData();

function AddDynamicData() {
        var valuesContacts = eval('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Contact))');
        var valuesAddresses = eval('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Address))');

        if (valuesContacts != null) {
            var iContact = 0;
            $(valuesContacts).each(function () {
                $("#divContact").append(GetDynamicContact(iContact++, valuesContacts.contactType, valuesContacts.mobile, valuesContacts.email));
            });
        }

        if (valuesAddresses != null) {
            var iAddress = 0;
            $(valuesAddresses).each(function () {
                $("#divAddress").append(GetDynamicAddress(iAddress++, valuesAddresses.addressType, valuesAddresses.addressName, valuesAddresses.addressLine1, valuesAddresses.addressLine2, valuesAddresses.city, valuesAddresses.state, valuesAddresses.postCode));
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

The Function does not work properly, It does create the field but does not populate the user input data into textbox... Please advise how to fix the same and how to populate the records in view....

[Added the View after submitting the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm0ZW.png)

```
<Update>
    #Updated New Code with function & added screenshot
</Update>
```